# How can I combine two event observers (childAdded and childRemoved) in Firebase realtime DB?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, combine

I am building a Combine pipeline which monitors for the immediate child in a Firebase node and use a passthrough subject to convert the observer to a publisher to dispatch observers based on the changed child's key. However, I need to combine the observers for childAdded and childRemoved into a single observer. What I tried is to use two separate observers for each, but then the initial snapshot gets called twice.

```
    let childAddedHandle = userDatabaseRef!
        .observe(DataEventType.childAdded) { snapshot in
            self.memberPS.send(snapshot) // memberPS is a passthrough subject and I use it downstream to dispatch observers
        }
    let childRemovedHandle = userDatabaseRef!
        .observe(DataEventType.childRemoved) { snapshot in
            self.memberPS.send(snapshot)
        }
```

I have read the documentation on observing events in list of data in the firebase documentation, but there is no explanation in there on how to combine two events. There might be a simple solution to this, but I'm stuck on this for some time and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine into a single observer"? What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: threre are two .send(snapshot) in the code I have presented. The issue with the code is that the initial snapshot data is returned twice. Actually I have, for now, used dropFirst to discard one of the initial data, but I'm not sure if this is a viable scalable solution in case I add one more event type to observe.

Comment: I see. After a brief look, there doesn't appear to be a single observer for both `childAdded` and 'childRemoved' (but I'm not familiar with the Firebase SDK). `dropFirst` is one such approach. Another might be `removeDuplicates`